# How to initiate a TCP secure connection using LibGdx to a remote server?

Tags: libgdx

Can anyone point to a link or share with me a piece of code which does:
- Base on LibGdx (Gdx.net package)
- Use a TCP secure connection to connect to a remote server

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Networking):

```
Socket socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol protocol, String host, int port, SocketHints hints);
```